# Group dates by bimester

Tags: r, date, strptime, strftime

Here is a sample of the data I'm currently working on:

```
x <- structure(list(sec   = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                    min   = c(59L, 32L, 23L, 26L, 20L, 14L, 1L, 5L, 32L, 2L),
                    hour  = c(10L, 15L, 12L, 12L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 9L, 14L, 12L),
                    mday  = c(9L, 15L, 2L, 15L, 20L, 26L, 11L, 22L, 9L, 16L),
                    mon   = c(4L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 4L),
                    year  = c(111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L),
                    wday  = c(1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L),
                    yday  = c(128L, 348L, 305L, 226L, 292L, 268L, 314L, 264L, 251L, 135L),
                    isdst = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)),
               .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year",
                          "wday", "yday", "isdst"),
               class  = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"))
```

So that

```
> x
 [1] "2011-05-09 10:59:00" "2011-12-15 15:32:00" "2011-11-02 12:23:00"
 [4] "2011-08-15 12:26:00" "2011-10-20 16:20:00" "2011-09-26 18:14:00"
 [7] "2011-11-11 18:01:00" "2011-09-22 09:05:00" "2011-09-09 14:32:00"
[10] "2011-05-16 12:02:00"
```

Say I want to tabulate the distribution of `x` by month. This is how I accomplish it:

```
> table(strftime(x, '%m'))

05 08 09 10 11 12 
 2  1  3  1  2  1
```

Now I want to do a similar tabulation, but this time I want to **group the data by bimester** (and possibly by trimester or semester, later on). I've taken a look at the [help page for `strptime`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/strptime.html), but couldn't find an appropriate separator.

This is the best I have come up with so far:

```
> table(cut(x      = as.numeric(strftime(x, '%m')),
            breaks = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13),
            labels = c('1-2', '3-4', '5-6', '7-8', '9-10', '11-12'),
            right  = FALSE))

  1-2   3-4   5-6   7-8  9-10 11-12 
    0     0     2     1     4     3
```

It is a convoluted way of reaching this, but it's OK for a simple example and a single case. However, this approach will give me headaches down the road, since I'll want those data to remain POSIX (not to mention it makes my code scarier than it should). Is there an elegant solution for this?

Comment: Do you mean to exclude `12`'s from the `11-12` category?

Comment: @thelatemail, I didn't. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're sticking with `table` and vectors (as opposed to have a rectangular data/output, in which case I'd use `data.table`), you could do:

```
table(2*(x$mon %/% 2) + 1)
#
# 5  7  9 11 
# 2  1  4  3
```

Comment: Thanks, I've actually tried that transformation (with `%%`, though) in the original data frame. It helps, but I'm still looking for a better solution.

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio it might help if you defined your notion of "better"

Comment: Fair enough: ideally, I'm looking for a solution within `strftime`. Hope that's not asking too much. :-/

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio - why? You have a `POSIXlt` object, which already has a `x$mon` component for month ($mon is 0-11 not 1-12 though). `format/strftime` is extracting this data anyway, and doesn't have a "bimester" option, so you will have to do some degree of manipulation regardless.

Comment: @thelatemail, in that case I guess I'll go with the mod/quotient soluton. Maybe the problem is I'm having a hard time believing there are no such format options (trimester groupings are very common in Finance). I've even checked a couple of [time series packages](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html) but still couldn't find anything.

Comment: trimesters, or quarter-years, are no drama. There is even a `quarters` function in R. Bimesters on the other hand, I've almost never seen used.

Answer (score 1):

You could do away with using any type of `format`-ting of the date values themselves and just create a lookup vector for your groupings. This would also allow total flexibility in specifying what months fit into what categories. E.g.:

```
src <- factor(rep(c('01-02','03-04','05-06','07-08','09-10','11-12'),each=2))

src[x$mon+1]
#[1] 05-06 11-12 11-12 07-08 09-10 09-10 11-12 09-10 09-10 05-06
#Levels: 01-02 03-04 05-06 07-08 09-10 11-12

table(src[x$mon+1])

#01-02 03-04 05-06 07-08 09-10 11-12 
#    0     0     2     1     4     3
```